# Shell/awk script to read a column of files and combining columns to make a TSV file

Tags: shell, calculated-columns

I have over 600 files and I need to extract single column from each of the files and write them in a output file. My current code does this work and it takes column from all files and write the columns one after another in output file. However, I need two thing in my output file:

1. In the output file, instead of adding columns one after another, I need each column from the input files will be added as a new column in the output file (preferably as a TSV file).
2. The column name will be replaced by the file name.

**My example code:**

`for f in *; do cat "$f" | tr "\t" "~" | cut -d"~" -f2; done >out.txt`

**Example input:**

file01.txt

```
col1    col2    col3    
1   2   3   
4   5   6   
7   8   9   
10  11  12
```

file02.txt

```
col4    col5    col6
11  12  13
14  15  16
17  18  19  
110 111 112
```

**My current output:**

```
col2
    2
    5
    8
    11
col5
    12
    15
    18
    111
```

**Expected output:**

```
file01.txt  file02.txt
2   12
5   15
8   18
11  111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN {
   for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++)
      printf ARGV[i] OFS;
   print ARGV[i];
} 
FNR==1 { next }
{
   a[FNR]=(a[FNR]==""?"":a[FNR] OFS) $2
}
END {
   for(i=2; i<=FNR; i++)
      print a[i];
}' file*.txt

file01.txt  file02.txt
2   12
5   15
8   18
11  111
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments @anubhava. However, when I added third file:

file03.txt

`col7 col8 col9
11 88 13
14 55 16
17 66 19 
110 222 112`

It gave output:

`file01.txt file02.txt
2 12
5 15
8 18
11 111
2 88
5 55
8 66
11 222`

Also for my original file, it prints the comments (started with #) of the input files.

Comment: In the first line I mentioned "I have over 600 files and I need to extract single column from each of the files". @anubhava

Comment: Dear @anubhava, 

Your code works perfectly for the example data. Thanks a lot! However, in my real data, the output column values are ordered differently than the input file. In my case the column values in the output file should be ordered as in the input file. First few rows maintained the order, but later they did not. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear @anubhava ,

Many many thanks! It worked perfectly in my big data research.